# Looking for a mail app that only sends email without receiving new ones

Tags: mac, email

My "Problem": Every time I want to send a quick email I end up screening my other mail by accident. As soon as I open Spark (or Mail or Edison or Gmail or Thunderbird), the app fetches all my new emails. My best option is to try to close the window as soon as possible, but likely I will screen my inbox and lose my focus. I know this is a real first-world problem, but it bothers me terribly.

My goal is to be less distracted by incoming emails. Ideally, I would have **two** mail apps. *App 1* only sends emails all day long. The program can be open all day. *App 2* will only be started manually by me every day at a certain time or when needed, but actively triggered by me. Like opening my letterbox. *App 2* should then fetch all my emails so I can reply to them or archive/delete them all in one go.

I tried to find the setting in Spark, Mail, Edison, and Thunderbird to stop fetching emails.

Comment: Does Mail settings -> general -> search for new emails -> manual work for you?

Comment: How familiar are you with Terminal (it‘s rather simple to just send a mail from there)?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to be distracted then you can use following workflow:

- minimize Mail (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>)
- for sending e-mail <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇥</kbd> to Mail app (app is minimized, so it's not pops up but becomes active)
- use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up new mail window

This way you don't see your Mail program main window, only window for new mail you are about to write. Of course, you have to set all notifications etc in a way that they don't distract you as well.

Comment: Thank you Aivar! This is actually a pretty good idea! Used this for the last 60 minutes.